# Call PHP code from JSP Page

Tags: php, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use JSP and PHP at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025912/is-it-possible-to-use-jsp-and-php-at-the-same-time)

I am trying to call a piece of PHP code from my JSP Page. How do I do that? I normally use servlets but I need this PHP code for creating a particular report since it sorts the table fields dynamically which I am unable to do with my servlet. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

you could call PHP via command execution (exec() ?) from JSP and let JSP handle the output of PHP...